# Get size of polymorphic object

Tags: c++, polymorphism, sizeof, crtp

I want to be able to get the size of polymorphic object. At the moment I got this:

```
struct Base {
    virtual std::size_t size() const {
        return sizeof(*this);
    }
};

struct Derived : Base {
    virtual std::size_t size() const {
        return sizeof(*this);
    }
};
```

Which is literally copy & paste. I want to do better. Suppose I really hate macros and CRTP seems like the only sensible approach. Let us give it a try:

```
struct SizedBase {
    virtual std::size_t size() const = 0;
};

template <typename Type>
struct Sized : virtual SizedBase {
    std::size_t size() const override {
        return sizeof(Type);
    }
};

struct Base : Sized<Base> {}; 
struct Derived : Base, Sized<Derived> {};
```

This looks much better, but sadly is ill-formed: `Derived` contains two *final overriders* for `size()` from `Base` and from `Sized<Derived>`. We can solve this by inheriting *through* `Sized`:

```
struct SizedBase {
    virtual std::size_t size() const = 0;
};

template <typename Type, typename... SizedBases>
struct Sized : virtual SizedBase, SizedBases... {
    std::size_t size() const override {
        return sizeof(Type);
    }
};

struct Base : Sized<Base> {}; 
struct Derived : Sized<Derived, Base> {};
```

This works as intended, however gets somewhat confusing in the event of multiple inheritance and prohibits altering accessibility/virtualness of bases.

So, is there a better way?

Comment: A macro will look much cleaner and readable than what you did here...

Comment: Why do you need the size?

Comment: @n.m. for custom memory allocator that does not store size of the allocated block and requires it to be explicitly supplied on deallocation. But that is irrelevant to the question, same problem stands for any polymorphic type property besides identity (that one can get via `typeid`), like type name (`type_info::name()` is broken) or something like `clone()` defined via copy constructor.

Comment: I think a simple solution is to let `Base` and `Derive` etc. not derive from `Sized` directly, but only ad-hoc. E.g. if you need at some place in your code an object whose type is derived from `SizedBase`, then wrap it in one. Whether or not that's possible/efficient depends on the speed of move constructors for those types.

Comment: @dyp, that would work, but adds another vtable pointer. I would just store the size instead. However this gives me an idea: `struct SizedBase { virtual size_t size() const = 0; }; template <class T> struct Sized : SizedBase, T { template <class... Args> Sized(Args.. args) : T(args...) {} size_t size() const { return sizeof(*this); } }; template <class T, class... Args> T* get(Args... args) { return new (alloc.get(sizeof(Sized<T>))) Sized<T>(args...); } template <class T> void put(T* p) { size_t s = dynamic_cast<SizedBase*>(p)->size(); alloc.put(p, s); }` Which sadly fails when `T` is `final`.

Comment: Ah yes, I shortly had that in mind but forgot about it when trying another approach. Indeed, that will work fine. `final` for classes is the only feature I know that I'm not convinced (yet) that there's a useful application for it; see http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/why-make-your-classes-final/ In case the class is final, you could opt for the additional vptr.

Answer (score 1):

Not that anyone should really use this, but...

```
template <typename>
struct None1 {};
template <typename>
struct None2 {};

template <typename T>
struct PrivateBase { using Tpriv = T; using Tprot = None1<T>; using Tpub = None2<T>; };
template <typename T>
struct ProtectedBase { using Tpriv = None1<T>; using Tprot = T; using Tpub = None2<T>; };
template <typename T>
struct PublicBase { using Tpriv = None1<T>; using Tprot = None2<T>; using Tpub = T; };

template <typename K>
struct TriBase : private K::Tpriv, protected K::Tprot, public K::Tpub {};

template <typename T, typename ... Bases>
struct Sized : private Bases::Tpriv..., protected Bases::Tprot..., public Bases::Tpub...
{
    virtual size_t size() { return sizeof(T); }
};


struct Foo : Sized<Foo> {};

struct X{};
struct Y{};

struct Bar : Sized<Bar, PrivateBase<X>, ProtectedBase<Y>, PublicBase<Foo>> {};

int main ()
{
    Bar b;
    Foo* f = &b;
    X* x = &b; // error : private base
    Y* y = &b; // error : protected base
}
```

Virtual inheritance is left as an exercise to the reader.

The order of base classes is not preserved, but you should not depend on it anyway.

Something that is a little bit more production-friendly can be implemented like this (this is a rough sketch):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct myinfo
{
    size_t size;
    // any other stuff
};

using TypeInfoRef = std::reference_wrapper<const std::type_info>;
struct Hasher 
{
    std::size_t operator()(TypeInfoRef code) const
    {
        return code.get().hash_code();
    }
};

struct EqualTo 
{
    bool operator()(TypeInfoRef lhs, TypeInfoRef rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.get() == rhs.get();
    }
};

static std::unordered_map<TypeInfoRef, myinfo, Hasher, EqualTo> typemap;

template <typename K>
struct typemap_initializer
{
    typemap_initializer()
    {
        typemap[typeid(K)] = myinfo{sizeof(K)};
    }
};

struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() {}
    size_t size() { return typemap[typeid(*this)].size; }
    template<typename K, typename... Arg>
        friend K* alloc(Arg...);
  private:
    void* operator new(size_t sz) { return ::operator new(sz); }
};

    template<typename K, typename... Arg>
K* alloc(Arg... arg)
{
    static typemap_initializer<K> ti;
    return new K(arg...);
}

struct Foo : Base {int a;};
struct Bar : Foo {int b; int c;};

int main ()
{
    Foo* f = alloc<Foo>();
    Bar* g = alloc<Bar>();

    std::cout << f->size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << g->size() << std::endl;
}
```

Of course one gives up the familiar `Foo* foo = new Foo` syntax, but in the era of ubiquitous `std::make_shared<>` this is not a big problem.

Comment: Nice, have not thought of this. However private is broken here: private bases are private to `Sized<>`, not to `Bar` where they are inaccessible.

Comment: Yes it is probably impossible to inherit privately "through" a template. Nevermind, I have updated with something less hideous.

Comment: *production-friendly* version is regrettably not multithreading friendly. Adding locks is trivial though.

Comment: of course one needs to add locks and encapsulate stuff properly, this is just an idea that *could* possibly be put to production if developed.